# Internal service requests in Istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have managed to get going with Istio. I've been testing a lot of the fundamentals and have a basic cluster working nicely with HTTP and gRPC. I have a Service that however needs to make an internal request to another service that isn't externally exposed.

So take this example:

1. Request comes in from an Istio gateway as HTTP
2. My custom grpc-gateway handler proxies the request to a gRPC service
3. The gateway responds to the user via HTTP

I have a Gateway and a VirtualService declared:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
        host: my-grpc-gateway.default.svc.cluster.local
    corsPolicy:
      allowOrigin:
      - "*"
      allowMethods:
      - POST
      - GET
      - DELETE
      - PUT
      - OPTIONS
      allowCredentials: false
      allowHeaders:
      - Authorization
      maxAge: "24h"
  - match:
    - port: 30051
    route:
    - destination:
        host: api.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8443
```

And here's my gateway:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
    tls:
      mode: PASSTHROUGH
    hosts:
    - "*"
  - port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: PASSTHROUGH
    hosts:
    - "*"
  - port:
      name: grpc
      number: 30051
      protocol: GRPC
    tls:
      mode: PASSTHROUGH
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

My proxy service is being provided with the coordinates of the gRPC server:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rest-proxy
  labels:
    app: prox
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rest-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rest-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: redacted/rest-proxy:latest
          name: rest-proxy
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          command: ["./rest-proxy"]
          args: ["-host", "0.0.0.0", "-port", "80", "-apipath", "$(API_SERVICE_HOST):$(API_SERVICE_PORT)"]
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rest-proxy
  labels:
    app: rest-proxy
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
  - name: grpc-port
    port: 8444
  selector:
   app: rest-proxy
```

Is this where a ServiceEntry resource comes into play? For now I just want to make sure my internal services can talk to each other, eventually I'll create a load balancer to handle proxying from the gateway to the API (as I scale out).

Any suggestions/guidance would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much more digging I realized that my proxy service was binding to the port: API_SERVICE_PORT which was set to 8080. The gRPC service existed at 8443, so the connection was never made.

All internal services within the mesh should naturally talk to each other. It's only the ingress that needs explicit rules to come into the mesh.

Comment: How did you format the address. I'm having problems having two grpc services communicate to each other (though if access them from outside the cluster they work fine). I tried using `my-service.defaul.svc.cluster.local`, `http://my-service.defaul.svc.cluster.local`, `http://my-service` and none of these work. Any ideas on how too make them work?

Answer (score 1):

Virtual service is a layer above the standard k8s service which enables us to apply more rules and policies.

Service entry is mainly used to add services which are outside mesh to istio's internal service registry like database, message queues, etc (though we can add mesh internal  service also if required)

If both services are in the same mesh the should talk with each other over virtual service

If one service is outside and one is inside you have to have a service entry for the service which is outside.

Comment: They are both inside the mesh. one is called api.default.svc.cluster.local and the other is rest.default.svc.cluster.local. Should they be able to automatically interact with each other or do I need to declare their rules in virtual service and explicitly allow communication?

Comment: We are using Virtual services we haven't tried with direct k8s service. But my guess is it should work it both are under istio and you don't have deny all rule