# Istio Mixer on GKE missing promhttp and promtck

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, istio

My mixer is cannot send metric to prometheus because its missing the default configurations including rules `promhttp` and `promtcp`. Any ides on where I can get the default configurations?

Comment: Are you using the istio addon for GKE or did you install istio yourself using the helm charts?

Comment: I was using the GKE addon. I went ahead and installed it myself and all is fine now

Comment: @PatrickW I have a new problem though. Hope you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57469406/internal-service-requests-in-istio

Answer (score 0):

To clarify this thread.

You manage to solve this problem with a `manual installation of Istio` in GKE.

Instead of using a the Istio add on for GKE.

Update:

As I see the other thread already has been solve.